# Why does the wrapping exception disappear

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I don't understand the behavior of the following tests (written in C# using [xUnit.net](https://xunit.github.io/)).  I thought that `ThrowsWrappingException` would pass and `ThrowsCustomException` would fail.  Instead, they have the opposite behavior: `ThrowsWrappingException` fails while `ThrowsCustomException` passes.

Why is that?

```
[Fact]
public async Task ThrowsWrappingException() =>
  await Assert.ThrowsAsync<WrappingException>(InterceptException);

[Fact]
public async Task ThrowsCustomException() =>
  await Assert.ThrowsAsync<CustomException>(InterceptException);

private async Task InterceptException() {
  var task = ThrowCustomException();
  await Task.WhenAll(task);
  throw new WrappingException(task.Exception);
}

private Task ThrowCustomException() =>
  throw new CustomException();

private class WrappingException : Exception {
  public WrappingException(Exception e)
    : base(e.Message, e) { }
}

private class CustomException : Exception { }
```

Comment: Does `CustomException` inherit from `AggregateException`?

Comment: @ScottHannen No, thanks for asking.  I forgot to include its definition.  Just added it now.

Comment: Shouldn't you be catching the CustomException? Before wrapping and throwing?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I don't know what you mean by "Should".  This code is a MWE that expresses some behavior of C# that I do not understand.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: I mean that, (unless I'm rather mistaken), the "throw new WrappingException(task.Exception)" line will never execute, as your unhandled CustomException will be wrapped in an AggregateException and propagated to the caller (the unit test), which probably unpacks it, detects it as a CustomException, and terminates. So your throw statement never executes - I think you need a try-catch block.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Oh, you are right.  That line never executes.  You should restate this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: That's the same conclusion I came to. But that doesn't explain why the second test passes. The second test is expecting `CustomException` but it's going to get `AggregateException`. Unless, as suggested, `ThrowsAsync` accounts for the `AggregateException`. But it shouldn't. It would be bad if we could write a test that checks for one condition, a different condition occurs, and the test passes.

Comment: @ScottHannen: I'm guessing that it's because the OP is using Assert.ThrowsAsync (as opposed to Assert.Throws), which is probably designed to unpack the original exception. (But I'm not sure - would need to read the docs.)

Comment: I recommend to use `await task;` instead `await Task.WhenAll(task);`

Comment: @NikolayLebedev Of course.  Again, this code is a MWE of something that I was not understanding about C#.  In the actual code that motivated this example, there was more than one task passed to `Task.WhenAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the line

```
throw new WrappingException(task.Exception)
```

never gets executed, as your unhandled CustomException will be wrapped in an AggregateException and propagated to the caller (the unit test), which, I'm guessing, will unpack it and detect that it's a CustomException, and terminate.

So the throw statement never executes; you can add a try-catch block to change that.